# React Router v6 : How to render multiple component inside and outside a div with the same path

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to upgrade to `react-router-dom` v6 :

## v5

In version 5 it works like a charm:

**App.js**

```
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Topbar from "./components/topbar/Topbar";
import "./app.css";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import UserList from "./pages/userList/UserList";
import User from "./pages/user/User";
import NewUser from "./pages/newUser/NewUser";
import ProductList from "./pages/productList/ProductList";
import Product from "./pages/product/Product";
import NewProduct from "./pages/newProduct/NewProduct";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";



function App() {

   const admin = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user || "{}")?.currentUser?.isAdmin ;

  return (
    <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      {admin && (
        <>
          <Topbar />
          <div className="container">
            <Sidebar />
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/users">
              <UserList />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/user/:userId">
              <User />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/newUser">
              <NewUser />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/products">
              <ProductList />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/product/:productId">
              <Product />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/newproduct">
              <NewProduct />
            </Route>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## v6

When upgraded to v6 I changed my code to be like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  {admin && (
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<Topbar />}/>
      <Route path="/" element={
        <>
          <div className="container">
            <Route index element={<Sidebar/>}/>
            <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
            <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />} />
            <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
            <Route path="/productList" element={<ProductList />} />
            <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />} /> 
            <Route path="/newProduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
          </div>
        </> 
      }
    </>
  )}
</Routes>
```

This is my css file for `App.js`

**Notice**: the `Topbar` component should be outside the div, and react router didn't recognize the components inside the as routes even without div, that means each component should have a unique path, I tried also two components with the same path like this:

`<Route path="/" element = {<><Home/><Sidebar/><>}`, but the css is not taking effect

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

It doesn't work. I tried different code and I searched a lot without finding any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the issue is that you are rendering multiple identical paths, i.e. two `"/"` paths and two nested index paths. This won't work.

In `react-router-dom` v6 you can create what are called layout components. The layout components can render your headers and footers, sidebars, drawers, and general content layout elements, *and importantly* an `Outlet` component for the nested/wrapped `Route` components to be rendered into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = ({ admin }) => admin ? (
  <>
    <Topbar />
    <div className="container">
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </>
) : null;
```

Render the layout component into a `Route` wrapping the routes you want to be rendered into the specific layout.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
  <Route element={<AppLayout admin={admin} />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
    <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />} />
    <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
    <Route path="/productList" element={<ProductList />} />
    <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />} />
    <Route path="/newProduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: that's worked for me , thank you so much , but i searched for a solution and i didnt find the layout idea in react router v6 docs

Comment: @chihebloussif https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes and https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-route

Answer (score 1):

I will share working code from my project, hope this will help you.

Try to create a component layout that should look something like this:

```
// Layout.js
import React from "react";
import { NavBar } from "./SidebarNav";
export const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="block">
        <NavBar />
        <div className="w-full ">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

and then create routes in a similar way:

```
// routes.js
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Layout } from "./layout/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import { ItemList } from "./pages/ItemList";

const BaseRouter = () => (
  <>
    <Layout>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/item-list/" element={<ItemList />} />
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  </>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

Splitting routes into a separate file gives you more freedom and, above all, makes your code more accessible.

```
// App.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import BaseRouter from "./routes";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <BaseRouter />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```